Bootstrap modal.show() fired instantly instead of waiting asynchronously
I have a form submission that call an API like
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary w-100"
          data-bs-toggle="modal"
          data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
          onclick="Send();"
        >
          Invia
        </button>

Where the Send() function is
function Send() {
  var select_file = document.getElementById("formFile").files[0];
  var select_project_name = document.getElementById("selec-div").value;
  var pacchetto_id = document.getElementById("pacchetto").value;
  var versione_id = document.getElementById("versione").value;
  var file_string =
    "https://<xxxx>.it/api/;
  console.log(file_string);

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", select_file);

  fetch(file_string, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "PRIVATE-TOKEN": TOKEN,
    },
    body: formData,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("File uploaded successfully:", data);
      if (data["message"] == "201 Created") {
        modal.show();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
    });
}

My issue is that the modal pops open just after I clicked the button, instead of being shown after the data["message"] == "201 Created"
Basically even if I see the console.log("File uploaded successfully:", data); when the file is actually uploaded, instead the modal shows right after the button click

You need to remove data-bs-* attributes from button, as they trigger modal automatically, and show/hide modal only with JS:
  <button
      class="btn btn-primary w-100"
      onclick="Send();"
    >
      Invia
    </button>

JS modal instance:
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal');

demo:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">

  <!-- Example Code -->


  <form abineguid="06622E9DA1A84EF183141C48C5CDF885">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
    </div>

      <button
          class="btn btn-primary w-100"
          onclick="Send(event);"
        >
          Invia
        </button>
    
    
  </button>

  </form>



  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>
  
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal');



    function Send(e) {

      e.preventDefault()

      var file_string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
      console.log(file_string);


      fetch(file_string)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("File uploaded successfully:", data);
          setTimeout(()=>{
           modal.show();
          }, 1000);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



